# Bipartite Graph Typo in "Modern Graph Theory" by Bollobas

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

I was going through [*Modern Graph Theory*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387984887) by Bollobas and this example on bipartite graph which states on the last line of page 6 that Figure I.1 is a bipartite graph.

[image: Fig I.1]

Fig I.1 has triangles as subgraph and triangle is not bipartite. Given the subgraphs of Fig I.1 is not bipartite, then Fig I.1 itself cannot be bipartite. Am I missing something/misunderstand the example?

Comment: The graph is tripartite (or $3$-partite), with vertex classes $\{1,3,5\}$, $\{2,4,6\}$, and $\{7,8,9\}$, so that's probably what Bollobas intended to write.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it appears to be a typo.

> [image]